# What does "=!= Unknown error" indicate on Heroku build?

Tags: python, docker, heroku

I have a Django application running on Heroku with a `web` dyno on a `container` stack. On adding a `worker` dyno via my app.json and heroku.yml files, Heroku's build system for my Review app logs:

```
=== Fetching app code
=!= Unknown error
```

The application builds properly locally via Docker and via Docker Compose. It has been building properly on Heroku until I modified my `heroku.yml` file and `app.json` file to add a worker.

My questions are:

- What does "=!= Unknown error" signify? What part of Heroku's stack is throwing it, and what part of my configuration is likely causing it?
- How can I debug this problem?

### Relevant files:

heroku.yml:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  command:
    - ./release_commands.sh
  image: web
run:
  web:
    command: newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
  worker:
    command: newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py rqworker app
    image: web
```

app.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "stack": "container",
  "formation": {
    "web": {
      "quantity": 1
    },
    "worker": {
      "quantity": 1
    }
  },
  "environments": {
    "review": {
      "formation": {
        "web": {
          "quantity": 1,
          "size": "hobby"
        },
        "worker": {
          "quantity": 1,
          "size": "hobby"
        }
      },
      "addons": [
        "heroku-redis",
        {
          "plan": "heroku-postgresql",
          "options": {
            "version": 13
          }
        }
      ],
      "env": {
        "DEBUG": 1,
        "ENVIRONMENT": "dev",
        "ALLOWED_HOST": ".herokuapp.com",
        "CSRF_TRUSTED_DOMAIN": "*.herokuapp.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the next person to encounter this problem: this was a malformed `heroku.yml` that fails to log properly under some conditions.

Heroku expects the `run.<app>.command` to be an array. To work, the above `heroku.yml` file should be changed in the following way:

```
run:
  web:
    command:
      - newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
  worker:
    command:
      - newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py rqworker app
    image: web
```

Failing to structure one `run.<app>.command` as an array will cause Heroku to throw a YAML parsing error:

```
=!= There were problems parsing your heroku.yml. We've detected the following issues:
run.worker.command needs to be in array format, such as:
run:
  worker:
    command:
      - newrelic-admin run-program python manage.py rqworker app
    image: web
```

However, if all values of `run` are malformatted, as in the question, Heroku will fail to throw the error entirely and instead log:

```
=!= Unknown error
```